# Sublime color scheme for XML with Unicode node name

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, tmlanguage

If I use node name in ASCII, I have a nice view:

[image]

but if I use Unicode node name it is not pretty:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: The XML language syntax does not support non-ASCII tag names. What build number of Sublime are you using?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-non-eng-tags
Say that it is ok
build 3083

Comment: OK, thanks. I meant that *Sublime's* language syntax doesn't support non-ASCII characters, not the XML definition itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Background

The XML syntax highlighting language definition that ships with Sublime Text 2/3 does not recognize non-ASCII tags:

<sup>*Note:* The [Neon Color Scheme](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) is used for syntax highlighting</sup>

[image: original]

However, replacing it with the file in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MattDMo/39a9669b76f4a7529e3e) fixes that problem, along with a few minor things:

[image: new]

---

## How to install

### Sublime Text 2

In Sublime, open a new file and paste in the contents of the gist. Save the file to your Desktop as `XML.tmLanguage`. Open your `Packages` folder by selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**, then close Sublime. Scroll down to the `XML` folder and rename `XML.tmLanguage` as `XML.tmLanguage.old`. If it exists, delete `XML.tmLanguage.cache`. Now, copy the new `XML.tmLanguage` from your Desktop to `Packages/XML`. The next time you open an XML file in Sublime, it will use the new syntax.

### Sublime Text 3 Build <= 3083 (public beta)

In Sublime, open a new file and paste in the contents of the gist. Save the file to your Desktop as `XML.tmLanguage`. Open your `Packages` folder by selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**, then close Sublime. Create a new folder in `Packages` named `XML` and copy the new `XML.tmLanguage` from your Desktop to `Packages/XML`. The next time you open an XML file in Sublime, it will use the new syntax.

### Sublime Text 3 Build > 3083 (dev builds)

In Sublime, open a new file and paste in the contents of the gist. Save the file to your Desktop as `XML.tmLanguage`. Create another new file in Sublime with the following contents:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
name: XML-ss
file_extensions:
first_line_match: '^<\?xml '
scope: text.xml
contexts:
  main:
    - match: ''
---
```

Save this file to your Desktop as `XML.sublime-syntax`. Open your `Packages` folder by selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**, then close Sublime. Create a new folder in `Packages` named `XML` and copy the new `XML.tmLanguage` and `XML.sublime-syntax` files from your Desktop to `Packages/XML`. The next time you open an XML file in Sublime, it will use the new syntax. There will be a new entry in the syntax menu called `XML-ss` (for **s**ublime-**s**yntax), just ignore it.

---

## How it works

### Sublime Text 2

Here, we simply replace the old language definition (`.tmLanguage` file) with the new one.

### Sublime Text 3

In Sublime Text 3, the default packages (and many that you install with Package Control) are stored in a separate directory as zipped `.sublime-package` files. However, if you create a folder and file in the `Packages` folder with the same name as a package (`XML` in this case) and file contained within it, the version in `Packages` will override the version in the `sublime-package` archive. For ST3 builds 3083 and before, the same XML-based `.tmLanguage` format as ST2 was used.

However, starting with dev build 3084 and beyond, a new YAML-based `.sublime-syntax` format was introduced, and all of the default syntax definitions were converted. The `.tmLanguage` format is still supported, however, but we needed to override the `XML/XML.sublime-syntax` file first in order for our new `.tmLanguage` file to be used.